# Running a process as another user in Restricted SCC in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, okd

Is there a way of running a process in a container which is running under `Restricted` SCC in `OpenShift`? Given that the Restricted SCC has `SETUID` listed in its `Drop` Capabilities. Are there recommended or unofficial workarounds for that?

```
oc describe scc restricted
Name:                                           restricted
Priority:                                       <none>
Access:
  Users:                                        <none>
  Groups:                                       system:authenticated
Settings:
  Allow Privileged:                             false
  Allow Privilege Escalation:                   0xc042500f4c
  Default Add Capabilities:                     <none>
  Required Drop Capabilities:                   KILL,MKNOD,SETUID,SETGID
  Allowed Capabilities:                         <none>
  Allowed Seccomp Profiles:                     <none>
```

Comment: Short answer, no. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html and https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks a lot for those link!